# Execution order of cruisecontrol.net blocks

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Couldn't find any documentation about this: what is the order of execution of the different blocks of a cruisecontrol.net config file (e.g. *sourcecontrol*, *prebuild*, *tasks*)?

Specifically I'd like to know whether *sourcecontrol* is executed before or after the *prebuild* block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [this page](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Task+And+Publisher+Blocks) has the answer:

- The `<tasks>` section is always run before the `<publishers>` section, regardless of the order in which they appear.
- However, within each of these sections, the tasks are run in the order they appear.
- The `<prebuild>` section is intended for tasks which need to be run before the build starts, including the sourcecontrol operation.

So the order is:

1. **prebuild**
2. **sourcecontrol**
3. **tasks** (in the order in which they appear in the config file)
4. **publishers** (in the order in which they appear in the config file)

Answer (score 0):

I think the order is

```
1.sourcecontrol
2.tasks
   a.msbuild
   b.exec
3.publishers
```

Please check the [link](http://www.softwareassociates.in/blog/implementation-of-continuous-integration/)